# Unix time difference in minutes gives unexpected results

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following simple code for testing:

```
$start_time_unix = time();
$end_time_unix = time();
$seconds_diff = $end_time_unix - $start_time_unix;    
$duration = round(abs($seconds_diff/1000) / 60,2);
```

When i store it in MySQL (int), the results are big values like 25634 even for a few seconds. How can i get the minutes, even in fraction of minutes?? What is wrong with my code above ??

Comment: why are you dividing the seconds by 1000?

Comment: You can't store a decimal number in an `int` field. Try [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: @ Alberto As it is in milliseconds.

Comment: I am using php7.2. For all time values i am getting same value as 25634 ?? Funny. Seems like some bug.

Comment: Pamela, time() returns seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Okay. Newbie mistakes.

Comment: Then, how can you even think of saving the result of a division, even rounded with specifically 2 decimals, in a Integer column? Come on.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `int` cannot store fractions, so you will probably want to use `float` or `double` instead.

But why are you dividing by `1000`. `$seconds_diff` consists of a *seconds*, so dividing by `60` will give you fraction of a minute.

For example: If `$seconds_diff` is a value of `13` [seconds]:

```
$duration_in_minutes = round($seconds_diff / 60, 2);
$duration_in_milliseconds = $seconds_diff * 1000;
```

If it is your goal to use **milliseconds** then use `microtime()` instead of `time()`:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php

**Recommendation**
Just measure the time with `microtime()` and directly store the result in the database without rounding, dividing or formatting. Then later on, do the formatting when you have to output it. This will give you more precise results and more freedom.

```
$start_time = microtime();
…
$end_time = microtime();
$duration = $end_time - $start_time; // duration in milliseconds --> save to database
```

When outputting, for example:

```
$duration = get_duration_from_database(); // pseudo function
printf('%.2f minutes', $duration / 1000 / 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function returns the current Unix timestamp ***in seconds***. There is no need to divide it by 1000. Since MySQL is expecting an integer, you must round to 0 decimal places:

```
$seconds_diff = abs($end_time_unix - $start_time_unix);
$duration = round($seconds_diff / 60, 0);
```